# hibernate is not creating a table from model class

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to build an app using angular and spring MVC.
I have included the properties like so:

In stacktrace :

I am getting till:
Dec 19, 2021 6:25:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

I am not getting starting from this:
Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath

````
```
#SqlServer properties

spring.datasource.driver = 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/bookapi
spring.datasource.user = SA
spring.datasource.password = AccessSQL@21

#Hibernate properties

hibernate.show_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl_auto = create
spring.datasource.initialiazation-mode=always

#c3p0 properties    

hibernate.c3p0.min_size = 5 
hibernate.c3p0.max_size = 20
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment = 1
hibernate.c3p0.timeout = 1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements = 150
```


package com.bookapi.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Book")

public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String title;
private String author;
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
````

https://github.com/web-dot/Angular-Springmvc-bookapp

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` and please use just one @ComponentScan, for example `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.bookapi")`

Comment: yes

@Entity
@Table(name="Book")

public class Book {

Comment: https://github.com/web-dot/Angular-Springmvc-bookapp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bookapi/model/Book.java

Comment: Can you try specify in WebConfig @ComponentScan model dir?

Comment: I tried that, still not working